# Cmake library of object libraries error: install includes target "mylib" which requires target "my_object_lib" that is not in any export set

Tags: cmake

I have a library which depends on multiple `OBJECT` libraries, defined like this:

```
add_library(openfastlib STATIC
  src/FAST_Library.f90
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:openfast_prelib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:maplib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:nwtclibs_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ifwlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:aerodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:aerodyn14lib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:servodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:elastodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:beamdynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:subdynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hydrodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:orcaflexlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:extptfm_mckflib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:openfoamtypeslib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foamfastlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:scdataextypeslib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:scdataexlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:feamlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:moordynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:icedynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:icefloelib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:openfast_postlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:versioninfolib_obj>
)

target_link_libraries(openfastlib
  versioninfolib_obj
  openfast_prelib_obj
  maplib_obj
  nwtclibs_obj
  ifwlib_obj
  aerodynlib_obj
  aerodyn14lib_obj
  servodynlib_obj
  elastodynlib_obj
  beamdynlib_obj
  subdynlib_obj
  hydrodynlib_obj
  orcaflexlib_obj
  extptfm_mckflib_obj
  openfoamtypeslib_obj
  foamfastlib_obj
  scdataextypeslib_obj
  scdataexlib_obj
  feamlib_obj
  moordynlib_obj
  icedynlib_obj
  icefloelib_obj
  openfast_postlib_obj
  versioninfolib_obj
  ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
  ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)
```

Each object library is defined in a directory which is at the same level as this directory. There is also a top level cmake file for the project.

I also have an install command like this:

```
install(TARGETS openfastlib openfast_prelib openfast_postlib
  EXPORT ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Libraries
  RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

However, when I run cmake (version 3.22.2), I get:

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "versioninfolib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "openfast_prelib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "maplib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "nwtclibs_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "ifwlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "aerodynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "aerodyn14lib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "servodynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "elastodynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "beamdynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "subdynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "hydrodynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "orcaflexlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "extptfm_mckflib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "openfoamtypeslib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "foamfastlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "scdataextypeslib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "scdataexlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "feamlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "moordynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "icedynlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "icefloelib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "openfast_postlib_obj" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenFASTLibraries" ...) includes target "openfastlib" which requires target "versioninfolib_obj" that is not in any export set.
```

Why am I getting this error, and how should I address it?

Incidentally this is a legacy code base I am working on, which I was modifying to build a library from object libraries, instead of linking together a bunch of other libraries which are also built and installed. The motivation was that I thought the previous method was resulting in missing symbols when making a static library.

The question [install EXPORT problem for library with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378528/install-export-problem-for-library-with-dependencies) does not address this as it does not refer to OBJECT type libraries which on would not want to install, but rather only normal libraries.

Comment: What puzzles me, if you have added the `TARGET_OBJECTS` from all your `OBJECT` libraries to the static lib, why do you add the target libraries in the `target_link_libraries` command too?

Comment: You got the error because you link (in non-PRIVATE manner) the target `openfastlib`, which is exported, to target `versioninfolib_obj` (and others) which is not exported. Instead of exporting object targets, consider to use PRIVATE linkage with them, or even remove that linkage, as vre suggests.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I actually separately discovered I should be adding the object library to their own respective install targets. See the [kitware cmake gitlab issue here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18935). This solves the problem. They are then converted to INTERFACE libraries.

Comment: @vre, the answer to your question is that I developed this from a code which was linking actual built libraries to create the library. I take it I can delete them from the target_link_libraries now then.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, incidentally, I did see the linked question, but it is about real libraries not object libs, and I assumed I wouldn't want to be installing object libs, and a commenter even asks the question of an answer of what to do when you don't want to install the library.

Comment: "I assumed I wouldn't want to be installing object libs, and a commenter even asks the question of an answer of what to do when you don't want to install the library." - According to the [documentatoion](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html), CMake perfectly allows to install OBJECT libraries. If you mean [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378528/install-export-problem-for-library-with-dependencies#comment103643896_5379238), then its reply points to other question, which suggests PRIVATE linkage. I have added corresponding answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: As for [bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18935) you refers to, a solution suggested by the developers (e.g. that one: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18935#note_520410) is installing OBJECT library but without object files. According to latest [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html), this ability has been implemented. So the error with OBJECT libraries doesn't differ a lot from other kind of libraries: for overcome the error one need either to install the library or make the linkage PRIVATE.