How to export a static library linked to an interface library?
I have successfully built and exported a shared library of mine by following the approach of putting the compiler flags into a separate INTERFACE library, as suggested in the CMake tutorial.
I also need an exportable static version of my library but I am struggling to make the things work. Please consider the following CMakeFile.txt file that is a minimal reproducible example of my problem:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(my_project LANGUAGES C)

# Example of interface library for compiler settings
add_library(compiler_flags INTERFACE)
target_compile_options(compiler_flags INTERFACE "-Wall")

# Real library
add_library(Foo STATIC foo.c) # It works with "SHARED" but not with "STATIC"
target_link_libraries(Foo PRIVATE compiler_flags) 

# Install the real library
install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooTargets)

# Install the configuration targets
install(
  EXPORT FooTargets
  NAMESPACE Foo::
  FILE FooTargets.cmake
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo)

When I run cmake -B build, I get:
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "FooTargets" ...) includes target "Foo" which requires target "compiler_flags" that is not in any export set.

How can I make it work while keeping the compiler options in a separate INTERFACE library?
PS: I also looked at the static vs shared example in the official tutorial but, in that scenario, the static library is not directly exported (i.e., it is a private component of the exported shared library).

Just additionally install the library compiler_flags: install(TARGETS compiler_flags EXPORT FooTargets).

@Tsyvarev Thanks, that works. The drawback is that I have to install/export/expose something that I don't want and that there is no need to. But I think there is no other way when putting the compiler flags into a separate INTERFACE library...isn't it?

Oh, you have PRIVATE linkage of compiler_flags in your code. I agree that needing to install that library looks strange. Probably, it is because of STATIC type of your installed library (Foo): see that my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080574/3440745

@Tsyvarev I have just read it and it is interesting, I don't think that my case is covered by the two cases you wrote, because I have no header to be included nor compiler_flags is SHARED or STATIC (it is INTERFACE). Maybe you need to add a third case..or do you have another idea?

It kinda makes sense that you need to export compiler flags with static library. Whatever you compile and link with it should use the same flags or you can end up with errors.

I guess it depends on which flags, @Xellos.  In general, no, you don't need to compile different objects using the same compiler flags in order to use them together.  There are exceptions, however.

@Xellos I do not agree in general. Take the example library I posted in the OP, where I only set the compiler warnings. It is not necessary for a downstream project to enable the same flag to link it.

Yes, it's not the problem that'd appear right now & right here, but should CMake be equipped to handle it just for that reason? What if you decide to add a flag that changes the situation? Even the example from the tutorial can cause problems errors depending on specific standard and (different) compiler versions used. "What sort of flags did you build your static version with?" is a question I've had to answer and in fact I should've just exported them like this.

@Xellos Could you provide an example, please, where the flags are necessary to link a static library and not a shared one?
